# Does this type of metric have a common name?

Tags: terminology, metric

I tend to use metrics like the following:
"80% of all parcels are delivered within the given 60 min time period" or
"In 90% of all emergency calls, the rescue service is on the scene within 10 minutes".

Generally speaking, I use a percentile here in conjunction with another condition.

**Is there a scientific or at least common name for this kind of metric?**

Comment: You named it: "percentile."  The "other condition" part is not the metric.

Comment: If you show the complete distribution on a plot, terminology changes: it is an (empirical) (cumulative) distribution plot with percent on the vertical axis and a quantile plot the other way round. There are many more terms too.

Comment: @whuber That was my first idea, and it makes sense for the second quote about emergency responses. For the deliveries, however, the 60-minute window could be extended in either direction (too early or too late), so I am not as sold on referring to a percentile, depending on some specifics of the phrasing.

Comment: @Dave In that case I would suggest you are on the threshold of an explosion in terminology, because when (say) we use a metric like an arithmetic mean and write "the average diameter of the ball bearings we produced on this machine was less than 20 mm", there is an exactly comparable "specifics of phrasing" involved.  Why would using a percentile be any different than any other statistic in a comparison?

Comment: I've seen queuing theory papers refer to a similar metric as controlling the "tail probability of delay" (TPoD).